# Transient DC current on mixer output

Tags: operational-amplifier, mixer

I have an audio mixer with the following circuit (I omitted the input stage):
[image: Original circuit]

I removed the mono instrument output and used the jack connector as an alternative line-output.
[image: Modified circuit]

However, while doing so, I removed the DC path to ground (through R31) from the opamp outputs.

Was the only purpose of R31 to form the voltage divider to obtain the instrument level signal? Or is it important that a DC path to ground from the opamp outputs exist? In most mixer designs I see online there's no such path.

Secondly, when I turn on my modified circuit there's a DC signal on the outputs that exponentially fade's to 0V in about 3 or 4 seconds. This is strong enough to make my loudspeakers pop quite hard. What can be causing this? Is this related to the missing DC path to ground?

Comment: Your schematic is unreadable. Please use a white background.

Comment: You are right, sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made a very basic mistake in your schematic: -

[image]

Comment: This is a mistake on the schematic, the real circuit is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Opamps U5A and U5B do not output zero volt DC in the idle state, there's DC component =Vbias. The output DC separation capacitors C22 and C23 get charged through your power amp inputs and that's a long deep thump. Put back R29 and R30, connect the other ends to GND or put back also R31.

BTW the reversed regulator U6 hopefully is reversed only in the drawing.

Comment: Yes, the regulator is a mistake in the schematic, the real circuit is fine.